# Active Record - converting a SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble converting a SQL query to ActiveRecord and I'm hoping you can help.

```
  select tbl2.id
       from Table1 tbl1
              JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.some_column_id
       where tbl1.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
              and tbl2.id not in (10, 13, 22, 44, 66)
```

Rails Models exists and the relationship is like this:

Table2:

```
has_many :table1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed you setup your classes with appropriate table names (table1 and table2 are not good names for rails models, btw).

Then

```
Table2
  .select(:id).joins(:table1)
  .where(table1: { id: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }
  .where.not(id: [10, 13, 22, 44, 66])
```